# Using Swagger(2.9.2) in GET operation in a SpringBoot @RestController that takes a @queryParam(optional parameter)

Tags: spring-boot, rest, swagger-ui

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get list of Emp", response = ResponseEntity.class)
@GetMapping(path = "/getEmployees")
public ResponseEntity<Set<Employees>> getEmployees(@QueryParam("emp") String lastName) {}
```

**I have a GET operation in a SpringBoot @RestController that takes a query param. If I use Swagger UI, it throws an error that TypeError: Request has method 'GET' and cannot have a body. But if I change it to post it works considering the body is allowed in POST calls. How should I access query param in GET inside swagger? Not using curl. if I use Use Spring's RequestParam instead of Jersey QueryParam, it's no more optional, which I do not want **

Comment: Don't you mean to use `@RequestParam("emp")` instead of `@QueryParam("emp")` in your request? This is tagged with spring-boot and `@QueryParam` is used in JAX-RS.

Comment: No, I have rest API which uses query param as its an optional value. What I need is way swagger allows get with query param which is not happening for now.

Comment: Although I have tested it with GET as follows and it works, but if when I looked in swagger UI, it was passed in the body which I do not want as it is a query param...

public ResponseEntity<Set<Employees>> getEmployees(@ApiParam(value = "lastName", example="roy") @RequestParam@QueryParam("emp") String lastName) {}

Comment: if I use Use Spring's RequestParam instead of Jersey QueryParam, it's no more optional, which I do not want

Comment: @Roy you can make `RequestParam` as optional like `@RequestParam(required = false) String lastName`